# A short-lived bug in a web page which isn't even linked in the question, is a known-good review audit

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

When I saw ["Submit" for review button grayed out - Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286454/submit-for-review-button-grayed-out-xcode-6) in the [close review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6006364), I knew immediately that it was an audit (it obviously wouldn't have had the tags in my filter). I didn't bother clicking through, I just voted to close.

Turns out that a short-lived bug in a web page (off-topic), which isn't even linked in the question (unclear), is a **known-good** review audit.

So, no, the method to pick close/reopen review audits isn't working. It would only work if questions were getting closed properly in the first place.

The close review queue on SO can live or burst without me for a while longer.

Comment: (although I hate dumb selection algorithm) for the sake of completeness, it would also work if questions were downvoted properly in the first place. ["No close votes _or_ downvotes, ever"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/165773) (for known good close/reopen audits)

Comment: `The close review queue on SO can live or burst without me for a while longer.` - seems like quite a juvenile and self-righteous response for a bad review audit.

Answer (score -2):

"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Submitting your code for review to apple is a tool used by programmers.  Why it isn't working is practical and answerable.  The problem is unique to software development.

So it passes the first test.  The lack of link makes it a worse question, but it could be salvaged, and most experts will know where the link goes anyhow.

On the other hand, "Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." -- the problem will shortly not be reproducable, and it was caused by a simple typographical error.  But it wasn't caused by a simple typographical error **on the part of the submitter**, but rather in the version of the tool.  I think the typographical error clause is implicitly means "on the part of the submitter" here: and regardless, you first have to verify that it is a simple typographical error.

I'd say "close it, but only after they fix it on apple's website".  And in order to justify closing it by that reason, you'd first have to justify that it was nothing but a short-term error -- the fact that the apple website had a problem didn't mean it should be closed.

You just stated "you didn't bother clicking through".  So you didn't know it was a short-lived bug.  You lacked expertise, so you didn't know if the link to the website was required by experts on the subject to understand it.

In my opinion, you should have <kbd>Skip</kbd>ed, not <kbd>Close</kbd>d.

Also in my opinion, the problem once solved (at least by apple) should be <kbd>Close</kbd>d, as it would no longer be useful to future searchers.

So my position is you voted the right answer, for the wrong reason.

Note I am not an expert in the area either: so maybe that website isn't as famous among subject matter experts as I would expect it to be.

Comment: No, a bug in a website is not a “software tools commonly used by programmers”. Even if that website is used as part of a software deployment. Besides, since **the URL was not in the question**, “unclear” applied. I know when to skip, and this was not a time to skip.

Comment: You think the Apple App Store submission site isn't "used by programmers"? Who *do* you think uses it?

Comment: Why a third party webpage is broken is not _"answerable"_.

Comment: This same kind of issue in, say, javascript/html that linked to a page in the mdn or w3schools that had the same typo would still be closed as a simple typographical error, because that's what it is.

Comment: We should be voting based on the content of the question, not the actions of the user. Whether the user pulled the content from site a or typed it themselves, it's still just a simple typographical error.

Comment: @nit The implied question isn't "why", but rather "how do I submit my app for review".  This is not only answerable, but **answered** in the linked question (use firefox, modify the HTML, and it works).

Comment: @KevinB the problem wasn't "how to do this myself", but rather "how I can submit an app".  It was in how to use a (web-only) tool that is used by developers, not how to write some feature of that tool.  SO is both about programming, and tools for programmers: reading this as a tool question, not a programming problem, makes it answerable.

Comment: @Gilles what other website could they be referring to?  The website they are talking about is very clear.  It would be a better question if it had the URL, but as the URL/website should be famous among experts in the tags in question, the lack of it should not be fatal.  It would be like quoting the C++ standard in a C++ question or answer without providing a link to a PDF.

Comment: @Yakk Some other page that's part of that same submission process, for starters. Or maybe the asker had mistyped the URL and reached some testing page instead of the intended page. Or maybe his network connection had glitched. Without the URL, you can't try to reproduce these issues.